# Get "checked=true/false" value of checkbox from inside HTML attributes

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, checkbox

I want to enable and disable checkboxes based on two variables: 1) Is there already a checked count of 2+, 2) Is the current checkbox enabled or disabled. i.e. I have a list of items, and I want to limit the user to only selecting two out of (potentially) endless options.

I have a `handleCheck()` function, but I think by the time that's applied it's already too late to control the `checked` value of the checkbox, right? Because I can successfully call `alert()` after the user has checked their third box, but then the check appears anyway; I can't stop it from being checked. That's why I'd like to put the control inside the HTML: the checkbox will be disabled if the count is more than two and the user hasn't chosen this checkbox. In order to choose this checkbox, they'd have to deselect another.

What I essentially want to do is this:

`disabled={count >= 2 && thisCheckbox.checked === false}`

I'm using React to dynamically render checkbox + a whole load of data and visuals on a case-by-case basis, so it's not like all the checkboxes are in one neat form.

I've tried various SO threads but most of them use jQuery or do their handling in JS in the `onChange` function (`handleCheck()`, in my case), which is already too late because the check will still be applied (as far as I know).

**EDIT**

Here's a sandbox link with the basic set up: https://codesandbox.io/s/nameless-sun-3jsmn?file=/src/TestimonialsSettingsUnit.js

Comment: What have you tried so far? Could you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: May you edit the question and a runnable snippet? Preferably with the html too?

Comment: You need to hold the state of each checkbox (perhaps as an array of booleans) in your component state (or props) somewhere, then you should be able to use this to individually set the `disabled` property of each checkbox correctly. It's hard to be more specific without seeing some of your actual component's code though.

Comment: Added a sandbox link to show you my current set up.

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead. Stackoverflow does support [inline live demos](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: @Quentin This doesn't depend on an external resource. Everything it depends on is in the minimal reproducible example I put in the codesandbox.

Comment: @crevulus – The codesandbox **is** an external resource!

Comment: @Quentin There's a billion and one threads with code sandboxes, and the other commenters asked specifically for a snippet. That's what's in the code sandbox.

Comment: Could you please explain what is the logic for `showCount`. What is your intent when `showCount` changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the issue and you can refer working code here - https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-tereshkova-f95jj?file=/src/App.js

```
import "./styles.css";

import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

import TestimonialsSettingsUnit from "./TestimonialsSettingsUnit.js";

const data = [
  {
    name: "Test1",
    id: 1,
    otherData: "This is a testimonial about Test1",
    show: true
  },
  {
    name: "Test2",
    id: 2,
    otherData: "This is a testimonial about Test2",
    show: true
  },
  {
    name: "Test3",
    id: 3,
    otherData: "This is a testimonial about Test3",
    show: false
  }
];

const App = () => {
  const [selectedTestimonials, setSelectedTestimonials] = useState([]);
  const [testimonials, setTestimonials] = useState(data);

  useEffect(() => {
    const selectedTestimonials = testimonials
      .filter(({ show }) => show)
      .map(({ id }) => id);
    setSelectedTestimonials(selectedTestimonials);
  }, [testimonials]);

  const handleCheckboxChange = (testimonialId, show) => {
    const updatedTestimonials = testimonials.map((testimonial) => {
      if (testimonial.id === testimonialId) {
        return {
          ...testimonial,
          show
        };
      }
      return testimonial;
    });
    setTestimonials(updatedTestimonials);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      {data.map((testimonial, i) => {
        const isSelected = selectedTestimonials.includes(testimonial.id);
        const isDisabled = !isSelected && selectedTestimonials.length === 2;
        return (
          <TestimonialsSettingsUnit
            key={testimonial.id}
            index={i}
            data={testimonial}
            handleCheckboxChange={handleCheckboxChange}
            isSelected={isSelected}
            isDisabled={isDisabled}
          />
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

```
import React from "react";

export default function TestimonialsSettingsUnit({
    data,
    index,
    handleCheckboxChange,
    isSelected,
    isDisabled
}) {
    const handleCheck = (event) => {
        const { target: { checked } } = event
        handleCheckboxChange(data.id, checked)
    };

    return (
        <div className="settings-testimonials-container">
            <h4>Testimonial {index + 1}</h4>
            <div className="settings-testimonial-controls">
                <img
                    className="settings-profile-img"
                    src={data.authorPhoto}
                    alt="User"
                />
                <div className="settings-testimonial-info">
                    <div>
                        <p>Name</p>
                        <h5>{data.authorName}</h5>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <p>Company</p>
                        <h5>{data.authorCompany}</h5>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <p>Position</p>
                        <h5>{data.authorTitle}</h5>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="settings-testimonial-buttons">
                    <button>Delete</button>
                    <br />
                    <input
                        id="show"
                        type="checkbox"
                        name={`testimonial-${index + 1}`}
                        checked={isSelected}
                        onChange={handleCheck}
                        disabled={isDisabled}
                    />
                    <label htmlFor="show">Show on profile</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <p>Text</p>
            <p>{data.text}</p>
            <hr style={{ border: "solid 1px purple" }} />
        </div>
    );
}
```